# although I add the header file, class is not seen on Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, header-files

I have added header file to my view controller and creating instance of a class, but i am taking Undefined symbols for

`architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MedicineDownloadsView", referenced from: error.`

How to fix it?

My main view controller is as follows;

**header file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MedicineDownloadsView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
   MedicineDownloadsView *medicineDownload;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) MedicineDownloadsView *medicineDownload;
@end
```

**main file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize medicineDownload;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   medicineDownload = [[MedicineDownloadsView alloc]init];

   self.view = medicineDownload;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that MedicineDownloadsView.m is added to "Compile Sources" build phase of your target.